# WPF With Directx 11

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, directx, wrapper

right now i have a wrapper written in c++/cli, which is used in c#(WPF). This wrapper is wrapping a native c++ graphics engine into c# understandable code. But this isn't the problem(Wait...). So in WPF i have a Windows Control (Yes that is possible) that i recieve the handle from (HWND). All of this is great, and the frames are rendering, the only problem is the performance. The rendering is triggered as followed:

```
        ...
        System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(Render);
    }

    private void Render(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EngineWrapper.RenderFrame();
    }
```

So the fps is really low, meaning that the call rate to Render() is pretty low(because my application was origionally in MFC, and the framerate was much higher!). So I'm asking you, is there any way to boost this? A new way, another thread?(Must be possible somehow...)

Edit:
I create the windows control in the following way:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
            new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

        System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();

        host.Child = panel;

        this.RenderCamera_WorkareaGrid.Children.Add(host);
```

Thank You

Comment: Have you looked into using SlimDX or SharpDX (.NET DX wrappers)? What is the framerate you are getting?

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see which part is now going slower?

Comment: Alan: I have no interest in .NET DX wrappers right now...

Comment: ananthonline: No not yet, how do i do this?

Comment: @MiguelP What's your framerate which you are calling "poor"? Are you using D3DImage to interop? We use a Window Forms Control handle to interop, and not Render() I'm confused how are you using a Windows control handle **and** Render() from WPF?

Comment: Well, maybe it's not really the framerate, but there is an input lag.

Comment: Render() is a function made by me, it's not a pre-existing function. And this function calls the Wrapper's function: EngineWrapper.RenderFrame();

Comment: The hwnd (Handle) of the Windows COntrol is sent to the engine (Wrapper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need get access to surface, that rendering your scene, and send it handle to D3DImage of WPF system. look at codeplex how it was made.